# `Preload.js` failed to load some files on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, createjs, android-browser, preloadjs

`PreloadJS` stuck at a specific step when loading files on Android devices while everything works fine on a desktop browser and iPhone.

The loading process stopped at the final GIF file (as shown in the code). Why this GIF file could not be loaded?

This happened before with desktop browser, but with no error, But at that time it was caused by some non-standard mp3 files. How to deal with this kind of exception when failed to load/init a file?

Here is the code I used to load files.

```
var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["ogg"];
preload.installPlugin(createjs.Sound)
preload.installPlugin(createjs.SpriteSheet)
preload.addEventListener("fileload", updateLoadingProcess); // show loading process

showWelcomeText();
var resources = {
    change: "assets/sound/change.mp3",
    click: "assets/sound/click.mp3",
    collide: "assets/sound/collide.mp3",
    game_over: "assets/sound/gameover.mp3",
    reset: "assets/sound/reset.mp3",
    win: "assets/sound/win.mp3",
    interface_assets: "assets/interface.png",
    raining_serial: "assets/raining-serial.gif",
    background: "assets/background.jpg",
    text: "assets/text-" + LANG + ".gif",
};
var loadedResource = 0;
var manifest = [];
for(var i in resources){
    manifest.push({id: i, src: resources[i] + _VER_ }); //add version to update cache
}

preload.loadManifest(manifest);
```

### update

I found that some Android devices stopped at another point, the first image(interface.png), and I really don't know why because these browsers don't have a developer tool.

### update

The problem is solved by not using XHR for these image files, although I still don't know why. `var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);` could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

there was a WebAudioPlugin bug with handling errors and a few issues with SoundJS and PreloadJS integration that have been fixed in the latest version [SoundJS-Next](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS) and [PreloadJS-Next](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS).  I would suggest trying those and seeing if you still have issues.

Hope that helps.